# Swift3 & Xcode8: ’subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with a CountableClosedRange<Int>,

Tags: swift

**Error 1**:
When I am trying get the `stringValue` from Metadata shows above error in `Swift3`:

```
let myMetadata: AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

// take out the system and check-digits
let myBarcode = myMetadata.stringValue[1...11] //error
```

**Error 2:**
In extensions of String I write these to get `right(x)` and `left(x)` function to get substring:

```
extension String {

    // length of string
    var length: Int {
        return self.characters.count
    }

    //  right(x) and left(x) function to get substring
    func right(_ i: Int) -> String?
    {
        return self[self.length-i ... self.length-1 ] //error  
    }

    func left(_ i: Int) -> String?
    {
        return self[0 ... i-1] //error     
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for editing Shobhakar Tiwari & @Nirav D

Answer (score 30):

Use this extension for the countable closed range `[0...4]` subscripting

```
extension String {

  subscript (r: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> String {
    get {
      let startIndex =  self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound)
      let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.upperBound - r.lowerBound)
      return self[startIndex...endIndex]
    }
  }
}
```

or a safer version which checks the bounds and returns `nil` rather than an out-of-range exception:

```
extension String {

    subscript (r: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> String? {
        get {
            guard r.lowerBound >= 0, let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound, limitedBy: self.endIndex),
                let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.upperBound - r.lowerBound, limitedBy: self.endIndex) else { return nil }
            return self[startIndex...endIndex]
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 4 change**: You need to create a new string from the result

```
return String(self[startIndex...endIndex])
```

Comment: it works for to get right and left substring of string ?

Comment: It's supposed to work with both `right` and `left` functions.

Comment: I placed this method in my extension those errors gone . wow !! thank you @vadian

Comment: Swift is a pretty good language, but their string handling is the worst I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

I took inspiration from @vadian's answer and created a set of (Swift 4) extensions that make pulling substrings trivially easy. These do not bounds check, which is generally my preference since I shouldn't be deferring sanity checking to lower level utilities like these.

```
extension String {

    subscript (_ index: Int) -> String {
        return String(self[self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: index)])
    }

    subscript (_ range: CountableRange<Int>) -> String {
        let lowerBound = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        let upperBound = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)
        return String(self[lowerBound..<upperBound])
    }

    subscript (_ range: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> String {
        let lowerBound = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        let upperBound = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)
        return String(self[lowerBound...upperBound])
    }

    subscript (_ range: CountablePartialRangeFrom<Int>) -> String {
        return String(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)...])
    }

    subscript (_ range: PartialRangeUpTo<Int>) -> String {
        return String(self[..<index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)])
    }

    subscript (_ range: PartialRangeThrough<Int>) -> String {
        return String(self[...index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)])
    }

}
```